# getting terminal output while using android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

While coding, sometimes we'd like to put some simple `print` statements at some location just to see some specific behaviour, but, when running `android studio`, our app is basically running on a physical cellphone(in this case, just considering the cellphone and not an emulator), but, how do I make the print statements print to my computer's terminal?(Currently using ubuntu 16)

Answer (score 1):

`Log` calls (e.g., `Log.d()`) are recorded by Logcat. Those messages are visible directly in Android Studio in the Logcat tool window. If you really want to view Logcat in a terminal window, use `adb logcat`.

Comment: I don't quite know much about the `logcat` but the logcat window has a myriad of information, not just my print statements

Comment: @juztcode The logcat window has a lot of settings to filter the output. I suggest you learn about these since they are a great debugging tool.

Comment: @juztcode: "but the logcat window has a myriad of information, not just my print statements" -- Logcat is a system-level messaging log. It will contain messages from all apps and core OS processes. As Code-Apprentice points out, you use filtering options in the Logcat window to constrain the visible messages to the ones that interest you. For example, if you use a suitably-unique tag as the first parameter to the `Log` calls, you can filter on that tag using the "search" field.

Comment: @CommonsWare, for now, could you tell me how to filter out terminal outputs only?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, for now could you please tell me how to filter out terminal commands only?

Comment: @juztcode: Sorry, but I do not know what you consider "terminal outputs" to be.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think they mean filtering out the logs that are automatically generated by the system. They only want the logs that they are creating.

Comment: @CommonsWare, yes, it's as Hayes Roach mentions, I only want those outputs that I am explictly creating via the print statements, which  would otherwise be sent to the standard output i.e. the terminal.

Comment: @juztcode: [I covered that already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57481576/getting-terminal-output-while-using-android-studio/57481618?noredirect=1#comment101435372_57481618). If you want to only see your log output, you need to have something distinct in that log output that you can filter upon.

Answer (score 1):

Piggy-backing off what @CommonsWare pointed out, you can also use the *Run* window to see less of the system logs and information more specific to your actual run of the app.  This was helpful for me in the beginning but sometimes you need the verbosity of the Logcat window.  If you end up using the Logcat window, there should be a search bar at the top of the window that you can use to filter out specific messages.

For example, if you call `Log.i(tag, message)`, you can search for `tag` in the Logcat window and only those messages will be shown! Hope it helps narrow your search.